# Show HTML in element

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am trying to use [sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) and want to insert HTML below the title.

Find below my minimum viable example:

```js
let shareIt = `<div><input id="myInput" class="swal-content__input" placeholder="" value="This is some text"/></div>`

swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  content: `${shareIt}`,
  icon: "success"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions how to display my HTML from my `shareIt` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) for this, like below:

It is similer to Sweet Alert JavaScript.

```js
swal({
  title: "<i>Title</i>", 
  html: "Testno  sporocilo za objekt: <b>test</b>",  
  confirmButtonText: "V <u>redu</u>", 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2"></script>
```

If you want to USE Text box OR AJAX, You can use below script:

```js
swal({
  title: 'Submit your Github username',
  input: 'text',
  inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: 'off'
  },
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Look up',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (login) => {
    return fetch(`//api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText)
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        swal.showValidationError(
          `Request failed: ${error}`
        )
      })
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swal({
      title: `${result.value.login}'s avatar`,
      imageUrl: result.value.avatar_url
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.17.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom `content`, you need to pass a DOM `node`.

From: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-dom-nodes-as-content

> This might look very complex at first, but it's actually pretty simple. All we're doing is creating an input tag as a React component. **We then extract its DOM node and pass it into under the swal function's content option** to render it as an unstyled element.

(Emphasis mine)

Since we need to turn your template literal into a DOM node, we could use `document.createElement('template')` and then assign `innerHTML` to your literal. This will allow us to then call `document.importNode` (which returns a document-fragment), which we can query and pass the element to swal.

Note: How you choose to create the DOM node(s) from your template literal is up to you (for instance, you might be a fan of just calling `document.createDocumentFragment` straight up or creating a `div` element and assigning innerHTML that way...)

Snippet example:

```js
let template = document.createElement('template');

template.innerHTML = `<div><input id="myInput" class="swal-content__input" placeholder="" value="This is some text"/></div>`;

let shareIt = document.importNode(template.content, true).querySelector('div');

swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  content: shareIt,
  icon: "success"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```